# jquery ajax call is not calling the server side method

Tags: jquery

I am calling a server side method by using jquery ajax post method.But it is not getting called
Below is my code..

### js

```
var templateName = $("#txtTemplateName").val().trim(),
htmlHeader = $("#txtHtmlHead").val().trim(),
header = $("#txtHeader").val().trim(),
footer = $("#txtFooter").val().trim()

var templateData = {
    templateName: templateName,
    htmlHeader: htmlHeader,
    header: header,
    footer: footer       
};
```

i created the javascript object

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "template_brow.aspx/SaveTemplate",
    data: JSON.stringify(templateData),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.d);
        $("#divTemplate").find("input[type=text]").val('');
        $("#divTemplate").find("textarea").val('');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Error while calling the server!");
    }
});
```

and in server side i made a custom class with the above properties

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string SaveTemplate(TemplateVariables oTemplateVariables)
{
----

}
```

TemplateVariables  is the custome class

Can anybody help me on this

Comment: Have you checked in for example Chrome Developer tools Network tab whether the HTTP POST happens?

Comment: I see the 500 error in the network tab .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var templateName = $("#txtTemplateName").val().trim(),
htmlHeader = $("#txtHtmlHead").val().trim(),
header = $("#txtHeader").val().trim(),
footer = $("#txtFooter").val().trim()

var templateData = {
    templateName: templateName,
    htmlHeader: htmlHeader,
    header: header,
    footer: footer       
};
```

After this block of code write:

```
var strData={}; 
strData.oTemplateVariables = templateData;
```

And then in ajax call write "data: JSON.stringify(strData)" instead of "data: JSON.stringify(templateData)" as given below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "template_brow.aspx/SaveTemplate",
    data: JSON.stringify(strData),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.d);
        $("#divTemplate").find("input[type=text]").val('');
        $("#divTemplate").find("textarea").val('');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Error while calling the server!");
    }
});
```

It will work.